# Code to count a particular String in each line of a text file using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am new to the streams and I have the requirement to count a particular String in each line of a text file using Java 8 Stream. Does anyone have any suggestions or sample code?
Edit: I missed to add my sample code..Here is the code I have just started but I have no clue as how to use count() on the stream.

```
Stream<String> lines=Files.lines(Paths.get("M:\\GIT_CODE\\FIRE_CHAT_PARSE\\New Text Document.txt"));

lines.map(eachLine-> spliteLineToArrayofSTrFunc(eachLine)).forEach(eachLines->{
        System.out.println(eachLines);  
        System.out.println();   
});
        
private static Function<String, String[]> spliteLineToArrayofSTrFunc(String line) {
        return (String lines)->{
            System.out.println();
            return line.split(" ");
        };
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your attempts and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Suggestion: Look for a terminal operation named `count` under the `Stream` class. But remember, you might want to `filter` specific string before you count.

Comment: Try something first, and then post the problems you face.

Comment: I missed to put my code. Just edited my question.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of appearances of a particular word in a text file?

Comment: Let's say you want to find the string `lapse`?  Do you want the count to include the word `collapse`?  What if the line includes the string more than once?  You need to be specific in what you want.  Perhaps show some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about finding exact match with words separated by **whitespace** and also including words ending with `.` then you can do something like -

```
long count =
    strings.stream()
        .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("[\\s\\.]+")))
        .filter(str -> str.equals(wordToSearch))
        .count();
```

For below 2 lines, if you search for word `stream` then you'll get 3 as count.

```
I am new to the stream and I have the requirement to count a particular String in each line of a text file using Java 8 stream. 
Does anyone have any stream suggestions or sample code? Edit: I missed to add my sample code.
```

Comment: You can avoid the temporary array created by `split` by using `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("[\\s\\.]+" )::splitAsStream)`. This will also avoid compiling the regex pattern for every line.